# How to call html to jsp?

Tags: html, jsp

my html file having the search box and when click on search box it will go to the jsp file...

can you provide any sample code for this..

plz help me

Comment: You are saying that you already have the HTML-file. What sample code do you want?

Answer (score 4):

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/your/file.jsp">
  <input type="submit" value="Super smart posting to JSP form" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a HTML file. Let's call it searchme.html.

Your search box should look something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="search.jsp">
     <p>Enter Search Term:<input type="text" id="searchTerm"></p>
     <input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
```

I assume your search.jsp and searchme.html are in the same directory.

This form gives you a text field and a button. Clicking on the button will pass `searchTerm` to search.jsp. In the JSP file, get the parameter using `request.getParameter("searchTerm")` and assign it to a `String` variable.

Example:

```
String searchTerm = request.getParameter("searchTerm");
```

The name of the parameter must be the same as the search box id in your HTML file.